# Replace <img> with <div>

Tags: html, css, image, replace

I'm using the Chrome Plugin "Stylebot" to change the design of a website. So I have to handle everything with CSS. I cannot change the HTML or add any JS-Code.

I now have the following HTML-Code:

```
<img class="inlineimg" src="/designs/cyborg/misc/navbits_start.gif" alt="" border="0">
```

And I want that image to replace with a div-container with a background and some text in it.

I tried something like that:

```
img[class=inlineimg] {
   visibility: hidden;
}

img[class=inlineimg]:before {
   visibility: visible;
   width: 90px;
   height: 20px;
   background: blue;
   content: "Text";
}
```

I know that this is wrong but I have no idea how I can make that happen.

Comment: Won't work. Do you know if the img is followed by an element that can contain text? Then you can write `img + *::before {..}`

Comment: no. the img is in an <span> tag and appears multiple times on the site.

Comment: If the `<img>` is in `<span>` tag then why you don't try `<span>` `::before`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say ***the img is in an span tag***, so I would suggest to use **`span:before`**. Using **`img:before`** is not correct/valid.

> **[Note: The pseudo-elements generated by ::before and ::after are contained by the element's formatting box, and thus don't apply to
>   replaced elements such as , or to 
>  elements.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)**

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('>.inlineimg').length !== 0) {
    $(this).addClass('imgSpan');
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

img[class=inlineimg] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

span.imgSpan:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 90px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  content: "Text";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><img class="inlineimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" border="0"></span>
<p>-----------------------</p>
<p>without image</p>
<span style="padding:5px;width:100px;background:red;"></span>
<p>-----------------------</p>
<p>image not having <b>inlineimg</b> class inside span</p>
<span><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" border="0"></span>
```

Comment: but there are many SPAN container on the website. And i just want to edit the SPAN container that contains this img-class

Comment: @Daniel Is there any parent class of span tag which you can use in the css?

Comment: @Daniel if you cant have a particular parent class there is a `jQuery` solution for this. I updated my answer with `jQuery` solution.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to select a class immediately after an element (or another class) you can use the following format :
>   element>.class
>    Like so :

```
    img>.inlineimg {
         visibility: hidden;
    }

    img>.inlineimg:before {
           visibility: visible;
           width: 90px;
           height: 20px;
           background: blue;
           content: "Text";
    }
```

Comment: It's my very first answer in this community. When i try to edit it won't allow me to post it rather than in this ugly looking format ... Sorry

Comment: sorry but it didnt work. the image is invisible but no div appears :(

Comment: excuse me Daniel, what exactly do you want the program to do :) ? I can't quite understand ur question

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN ::before (:before)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before):

> The pseudo-elements generated by ::before and ::after are contained by
>   the element's formatting box, and thus don't apply to replaced
>   elements such as `<img>`, or to `<br>` elements.

You have to try and find another element that is close to the image to achieve what you are trying to do.